# Drupal Views Expose Filter Date Time Popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, popup, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I need to expose filter for date time field using popup calendar. But i could not choose 'popup' on form element options. Every time i choose popup, it automatically change it 'select'. And an error ocurre, which is: 'missing field type!'. What's wrong actually?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this module is installed and enabled http://drupal.org/project/date.

Check here to make sure it is enabled. *yoursite.com/admin/modules*

Comment: yeah, i've installed date module and enabled it. And it still like that.

Comment: I suggest you post a bug with more details on the date project page, it may also be related to this issue http://drupal.org/node/1432702

Answer (score 0):

Although it is beta, but check this [better_exposed_filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module, which will integrate with [date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module.